# Need to set ListView in multiple tabs in my android screen

Tags: android, listview, android-tabhost

Hi I need multiple tabs in my android screen, which i got by TabHost View by referring to

[In android, how can I put tabs in a view containing an image on top?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389909/in-android-how-can-i-put-tabs-in-a-view-containing-an-image-on-top)

But i need to set ListViews in each of the tab's layout...so can nyone help me with some code plzz..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried anything on your own?

Comment: @Andro-Yes, i want to modify my app to multiple tabs version. So I faced problems in its coding, because i was unable to fill the content area in each tab..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each of tab layout is a nothing just an activity which you combined with a tabhost, so simply do things like you do in activity , Also if you want to show list with tabs then you have to use TabGroupactivity class.

Comment: @Kabir- But I am working on Android 2.2...so according to my knowledge..TabGroupActivity class has problems on Android 2.2..Can you suggest something else...??

Comment: nopes !!  i have already done two projects on same and i dun think so. There was just some issues on backpress which i resolved. So better to go with tabgroupactivity. :) i will you a link of onBackpress .